# Safe Handles when marshaling Win32 structs (PROCESS_INFORMATION)

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, safehandle

I am in the process of converting my Win32 p/invoke code to use `SafeHandle` classes instead of the typical `IntPtr` handles.

While everything works pretty well in `DllImport` method signatures, I cannot for the life of me get them to work when marshaling Win32 structs (i.e. `PROCESS_INFORMATION`).

```
// This works without issue.
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Win32ProcessInformation
{
    public IntPtr ProcessHandle { get; set; }
    public IntPtr ThreadHandle { get; set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
}

// This does not work!
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Win32ProcessInformation
{
    public ProcessSafeHandle ProcessHandle { get; set; }
    public ThreadSafeHandle ThreadHandle { get; set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
}
```

The `ProcessSafeHandle` and `ThreadSafeHandle` classes work just fine with methods like `ReadProcessMemory` or `WriteProcessMemory`, but I cannot use them in Win32 structs like above.

Am I missing some kind of annotation magic?

Comment: I don't really know anything about .net but just looking at the `SafeHandle` class, its constructor takes two arguments (an `IntPtr` and a `bool` indicating ownership). I'm not sure how the marshaller could know whether the `bool` should be true or false.

Comment: Good point. I have tried making the constructor in my `SafeHandle` subclass take only the `IntPtr` (assuming `true` for the bool always). Still no dice unfortunately.

Comment: Just don't try to hammer it all into a single hole.  Use two declarations, one that you'll use *just* for the interop call and another, a class typically, to store the safe handles.  Compare to the way the [framework does it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,c50d8ac0eb7bc0d6), note the call to SetProcessHandle at the end.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, The marshaller uses the default constructor and has special knowledge of SafeHandle allowing it to set the handle. The specific subclass of SafeHandle is expected to provide a default constructor that passes in a suitable bool.

Comment: @Erik_at_Digit, did you pre-populate the handle field with instances representing invalid handles? I find I need to pre-populate SafeHandle variables used for ref parameters, structs might have the same requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know<sup>*</sup>, the interop marshaler does not support the use of SafeHandles in classes/structures.

So it works fine to replace `IntPtr` with `SafeHandle` in a P/Invoke function declaration, but it doesn't work to replace it in a struct. The handles in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure have to be initialized by unmanaged code that doesn't know anything about the managed `SafeHandle` class, so the CLR would need to have specialized knowledge of how to do the required `[out]` marshaling.

But no worries. There's nothing wrong with your declaration of the struct as-is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Win32ProcessInformation
{
    public IntPtr ProcessHandle { get; set; }
    public IntPtr ThreadHandle { get; set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
}
```

If you want, once you've called the function that fills a `Win32ProcessInformation` struct, you can create a `SafeHandle` object for each of the handle values stored in the IntPtrs. This will ensure the handles get closed when the object gets garbage collected (if you forget to call `Dispose()` earlier).

For process handles (as in this example), [`SafeWaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safewaithandle.aspx) would be a good choice, since all process handles are waitable. This saves you from having to do any extra work because `SafeWaitHandle` is provided already as a public specialization of SafeHandle. (Speaking of doing extra work, I assume you've already checked to be sure that the `Process` class doesn't already wrap the reason you're P/Invoking process APIs?)

<sub><sup>*</sup> This may have changed on some very recent version of the CLR; my knowledge is slightly out-of-date.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about `SafeWaitHandle`. Saves me from having to write the subclasses.

Unfortunately, the built-in `Process` class does not expose any way to access the process memory (`ReadProcessMemory` or `WriteProcessMemory`). I have created a stream subclass that wraps these methods.

Also, the built-in `Process` class does not allow you to create processes with flags (like suspended). So I have to use the `CreateProcess` Win32 API for this.